# "Missing Template" ao tentar usar JSONView no CakePHP 3

Tags: json, cakephp-3

Estou tentando criar uma resposta JSONView para minha aplicação. Segui os passos descritos no manual https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html, mas continuo recebendo o erro **Missing Template**, segue o código abaixo:

No arquivo **routes.php**:

```
$routes->setExtensions(['json']);
```

No arquivo **AppController.php**:

```
$this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
```

No arquivo **UsersController.php**:

```
public function fetch() {    
        $users = $this->Users->find();

        $this->set(compact('users'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['users']);
    }
```

Ao tentar acessar a url */users/fetch.json* eu sempre recebo o erro de Missing Template. O que eu posso estar fazendo de errado?